# zappa js @include coffeescript method doesn't work

Tags: node.js, function, include, coffeescript, zappa

I want to be able to call coffeescript and js functions declared in other files from a zappa app. I can't get it to work at all.

I tried using @include as explained on the zappajs [crashcourse](http://zappajs.org/docs/crashcourse/) ...

but I get

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'include'

Here's my test app code:

```
#app.coffee
require('zappajs') ->
    @get '/': -> @include 'call'
```

and here's the function I'm trying to call in another file.

```
#call.coffee
@include = ->
    "call me"
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested anything, but it looks like you're mixing up a few things here. I may be wrong, but you should probably either just use require `node.js`-style `require`, OR you can use `zappa` style `@include`, but mixing them is probably not a good idea until you really understand what `@include` does.

The zappa crashcourse you link to shows both defining modules and using them, but both places it is done using `@include`. Based on what you write I believe you can not mix `require` and `@include` the way you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
#app.coffee
require('zappajs').run port, host,  ->
  @include './routes'

#routes.coffee
@include = ->
  @get '/': ->
    @render 'index.jade',
      foo:'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Marius is right, I was mixing up require and @include ... I can get this to work, which is really what I was wanting to do (i.e. call a function in another file)

```
require('zappajs') -> 
  test = require('./test') 
  @get '/': -> test.test(@response)
```

with a file called test.coffee that looks like this

```
@test = (res) -> 
  res.send 'hullo'
```